# Overloading assignment operator without return statement

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

Why does the assignment operator is allowed to return void? And why does assignment chaining works in this case? Take a look at the code, it will be very clear what am I talking about.

**Code:**

```
struct Foo
{
   std::string str;

   Foo(const std::string& _str)
   : str(_str)
   {
   }

   Foo& operator=(const Foo& _foo)
   {    
      str = _foo.str;
      //return *this; /* NO RETURN! */
   }
};

int main()
{
   Foo f1("1");
   Foo f2("2");
   Foo f3("3");
   f1 = f2 = f3 = Foo("4");

   std::cout << "f1: " << f1.str << std::endl;
   std::cout << "f2: " << f2.str << std::endl;
   std::cout << "f3: " << f3.str << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is this legal? (why does it compile at all)
2. Why does it work?

I've read in many places "assignment operator should return **this* so that you can have assignment chaining" which totally makes sense, but then why does the above work?

**Try it out:**

   [online c++ workspace with the code from above](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1ghzjD%246)

Comment: It returns `Foo&`, not `void`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is this legal? (why does it compile at all)

This is **not** legal, and injects **Undefined Behavior** in your program. Your compiler should at least warn you about that (and I believe it does, if you set a sufficiently high warning level).

Per Paragraph 6.6.3/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; **this results in undefined
>   behavior in a value-returning function**.

The only exception is the `main()` function, which is allowed to have a missing `return` statement. Per Paragraph 3.6.1/5:

> A return statement in `main` has the effect of leaving the `main` function (destroying any objects with automatic
>   storage duration) and calling `std::exit` with the return value as the argument. **If control reaches the end
>   of `main` without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing**
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Finally:

> Why does it work?

Undefined Behavior means that your program may run on some machines but not on others; or it may run on all machines today, but not tomorrow; or it will cause your program to have some bizarre, unpredictable outcome; including (which is the *worst* case) seeming to run perfectly fine.

Comment: @Dario: No, I don't know. Maybe for compatibility reasons. Maybe this was allowed sometimes in the past and compilers may be still expected to compile legacy code. This is just a conjecture though. I do not know if this is allowed in C, but that could be another reason. Anyway, this is definitely illegal in C++, except for the `main()` function.

Comment: @Dario - for invalid code the C++ standard requires that an implementation issue "a diagnostic". The only time it requires that something not compile is for a `#error` directive. However, when something produces undefined behavior, it simply means that the standard doesn't say what happens; that's the case here. And the reason for it in this case is that it's hard to diagnose in more complicated situations. There are cases where one compiler doesn't notice the error and another one does; but with a small change, it goes the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is *undefined behaviour*, because you  are flowing off the end of a function that promises to return something.

The only function for which it is legal to do this in C++ is `int main()` (and version with arguments), because it implicitly returns `0` in the absence of a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Check what asm code is produced after compiling. My guess is that this function returns what happens to be in register AX (this is c-call standard function implementation if I'm not mistaken). In your case, it happens to be what you are wanting it to be... if you add some functionality to function you might break it...

Answer (score 0):

It's illegal and if it compiles, then in some way it is storing something weird for the runtime. And you must return `*this` from the function. The correct function definition will look like:

```
Foo& operator=(const Foo& _foo)
{    
  if(this == &_foo) /* check for self-assignment */
     return *this;

  str = _foo.str;

  return *this;
}
```

Returning `*this` is a must for chain assignments like:

```
Foo  x, y, z;
x = y = z;     /* *this is necessary for this statement */
```